# Bot acts differently in Microsoft Teams

Tags: .net-core, botframework

I've deployed my Bot to Webchat, Skype and MS Teams.

In `OnTurnAsync` method I check, if the user input begins with `bnr` then I call a specific method.

```
if (turnContext.Activity.Text.ToLower().StartsWith("bnr"))
{
    string msg = RequestHandler.BnrCaller(turnContext.Activity.Text);
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(msg);
    return;
}
```

It works fine with Skype and Webchat but with teams it does not work 100%, It works just sometimes.

[Edit]

I found out, that it does not work if I copied the input into the input field but when I type it, it works fine!

Comment: Interesting. What happens when it doesn't work? Just not call the BnrCaller? How often does it fail vs succeed? Have you attempted to debug locally using ngrok?

Comment: indeed! I found out the problem. I have often copied the text into the input field in MS Teams, then it didn't work but when I type it then it works :/
So the copied text is the problem! which makes the task more in interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out the issue by dint of app-insights.

I've added a `middleware`, which logs the request body into app-insights and just realized, that when I copy/paste a message like: "Hello", it would be logged in app-insights as something like this "\r\n\n\rHello\r\n\n\r\n". When I type it, it would be logged just fine. 
So I jsut remove these symboles from the request and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The Messages coming from the Teams are having a different structure.
The message text begins with the words `<at>...</at>`.
You need to delete this beginning in a Middleware component, etc.
Try to look at your incoming messages through NGROK at localhost:4040 in your web browser.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is the what I need! It works fine for every thing, just when I copy a text into the input field, it behaves unexpectedly